# how to install certificate

Tags: windows-7, certificate

Hi I was asked by a colleague to set-up a certificate to one of my colleagues laptop.

I was sent a link and a username & pwd to login to a ejbca site & told that I should only use IE.

My question is, do I have to open that link on my own laptop or to my colleagues laptop? Haven't done setting up a certificate, so not sure how to do this? 
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should open the link in the colleague's laptop, if it has IE installed.

The process can vary **a lot** between various setups, so no accurate answer can be given. But usually it's simple enough – log in, enter the required data (sometimes nothing at all is required), and the private key will be generated and the certificate installed automatically.